# get attribute throwing null pointer in JSP

Tags: jsp

Trying to set the String array attribute in the servlet and retrieve it in the jsp; however, the JSP throws a nullpointer exception.

**Java Servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  String [] yuh = new String[1];
  yuh[0] = "James";
  request.setAttribute("word", yuh);
  RequestDispatcher reqDisp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("form.jsp");
  reqDisp.forward(request, response);
 }
```

**JSP**

```
<form id = "Seeing" method = "POST" action ="mustWork">
<%String [] s = (String [])request.getAttribute("word");%>
<p><%=s[0]%></p>
```

Attempting to print "James"

Comment: mustWork is the name of the servlet

Comment: Just to be sure: the workflow should be like `A.jsp` calls (sends an HTTP request to) java servlet (your `doPost()` method), and then java servlet forwards to `B.jsp`. And what you show us as **JSP** is from the `B.jsp`. Right?